# asking for advice designing data storage in c++

Tags: c++

I am building a software to analyze log files from ArduPilot in c++.

The Data from the files comes in the fallowing form:
Sensor name (GYRO, Barometer, ect).
Each sensor has several fields of data, for example the barometer has the fallowing fields:
Altitude, Pressure, Temperature, Offset and some more.

All the inputs in the log file that record the Barometer data will have all these fields.
Example of line in log file:

```
BARO, 843762779, 0, -1.443359, 94956.91, 43.06, -1.074093, 843762, 0, 28.38455, 1
```

Here is the general idea:
list of Sensors: BARO, GYRO, BAT ...

Every Sensor has some fields

Every Field should have ether a float array, or a float vector.

This way I can feed the Graph module with the address of the vector to display the data of the field.

I would love some help how to build the data structure.
So I can easily add data every time I read a line with more sensor data.
Easily access an array/vector of a single field for graph display.

Any ideas?

---

Edit:

To clear things up:
I can have 100,000 readings per field X many fields per sensor X many sensors...

I can't make up my mind if to use vectors on the heap, of pointers to vectors on the stack.

Should I use somthing like unordered_map for quick access

```
unordered_map<int,somthing>
```

Where int is the sensor's id

Comment: Prefer `std::vector<>` over an array in C++03 unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: Advice is opinionated, thus off topic for stack overflow. Q&As here should be based on herbal facts. It's not a forum.

Comment: If you also have multiple sensors of the same kind but from different sites, you will also have some kind of sensor ID and you will have to worry about timestamps and maybe even about time synchronization of the sites. Since you mention graphing, you need to be able to filter the time series by type or something like that. My advice: start out simple with a `std::vector<std::variant<Baro,Hydro, ...>>` with one type of struct for each kind of sensor.

Comment: You should make a simplest possible implementation first, to get a better idea of the problem first. Then you could as a more focused question about how to make it more efficient. Also note that memory vs speed are often conflicting, and you should know which is more importnat... Is it fast enough but takes too much memory, or is there plenty of memory but data comes in faster than you can process it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can bundle the individual values in a `struct`? Something like:

```
struct Sensor {
    std::string name;
    double pressure;
    double temperature
    ...
};
```

and then collect all sensors in a `std::vector<Sensor>` ?

Comment: But then I will not have a vector with all temperature values that I can graph.
Graph (&temperatures) ...

Comment: Well if you can afford (by means of runtime and memory performance) you can prepare another vector that contains the temperatures `std::vector<double> temp`?  You can iterate over your data by using a loop (for example) `std::vector<Sensor> data; /* fill the vector with data */` ```for(auto&& x:data) temp.push_back(x.temperature)```

Comment: Ahhh :-)
Now you come to the gist of the question...
What is the best/prefer way to implement this?
Should I have it all on the heap?
Should I use pointers to vectors to have it on the stack?
I can have 100,000 values for every field...